# ¿Cómo modifico un input de tipo file?

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap, css3, bootstrap-4

Estoy intentando modificar este input de tipo file:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=El+Messiri:600');

html, body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 auto;
}
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #6a11cb 0%, #2575fc 100%);
}

/*Elementos Etiquetas*/
h1 {
  font-family: 'El Messiri', sans-serif;
  color:white;
}


/*Inputs*/

input[type=file] {
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Imagenes Momentáneas</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.5.0/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/styles/styles.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="row justify-content-center mt-5"><span>Imagenes Momentáneas<span></h1>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3 class="row justify-content-center mt-1"> Sube tu Imagen</h3>
              <div class="row justify-content-center mt-5">
                <input type="file" class="btn btn-danger" value="x">
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.5.0/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
      <script src="src/scripts/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

como pueden ver intenté agregarle estilos para que tuviera la apariencia de un botón, pero no logro quitarle la parte que dice seleccionar archivo.

[image: Esto es lo que quiero quitar]

Comment: @ShadowPaz Acabo de probar, pero le puse las mismas clases y todo, y no me funciona.

Comment: estas poniendo primero la llamada a la hoja de estilos de bootstrap y luego tu hoja personal de estilos?

Comment: mira http://jsbin.com/wumibaxabo/edit?html,output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Y si mejor escondemos el `input` y estilizamos el `label`.

Lo importante aquí es que el `label` tenga en su atributo `for` el id del `input`

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=El+Messiri:600');
html,
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 auto;
}

body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #6a11cb 0%, #2575fc 100%);
}


/*Elementos Etiquetas*/

h1 {
  font-family: 'El Messiri', sans-serif;
  color: white;
}


/*Inputs*/


/* Escondemos el input */
input[type=file] {
  width: 0.1px;
  height: 0.1px;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Imagenes Momentáneas</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.5.0/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/styles/styles.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="row justify-content-center mt-5"><span>Imagenes Momentáneas<span></h1>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3 class="row justify-content-center mt-1"> Sube tu Imagen</h3>
              <div class="row justify-content-center mt-5">
                <input id='file-input' type="file" class="btn btn-danger" value="x">
                <label for='file-input' class='btn btn-danger'>Selecciona un archivo</label><!-- Agregamos el label con su estilo -->
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.5.0/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
      <script src="src/scripts/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```